# How do I fetch points within a distance of another point on a map using NHibernate Spatial - without using SQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spatial

We are trying to display a map with data points within a distance of a reference location using NHibernate Spatial. However, the closest we could find was this:

[Get Points Within a Radius using NHibernate Spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917451/get-spatial-points-within-radius-using-nhibernate-spatial)

We need to do this without using any SQL or HQL. The NHibernate Spatial v4.0.0.x does not implement the IsWithinDistance() function on github as on date (of asking this question):

[IsWithinDistance not implemented in NHibernate Spatial](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.Spatial/blob/693ed215a7b8ef56404aeb76c25ad156ce5cca23/NHibernate.Spatial/Criterion/SpatialRestrictions.cs)

It will be great if you can point us to some solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Related questions:

[Almost the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427548/criteria-spatialrestrictions-iswithindistance-nhibernate-spatial) - But this one is closed. I don't think those are low quality answers. Someone should re-open it.
My question here is a more general question that the other one which is more specific to the investigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostGIS and are not *totally* against using SQL/HQL, I would recommend using the `ST_DWithin()` function (see [here](http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/)). For other providers (e.g. MSSQL), you can use a buffer and intersects query.

This "buffer and intersects" tactic can also be used in a QueryOver statement to avoid resorting to SQL/HQL. For example:

```
Point referenceLocation; // Will have been initialized somewhere else
double distance = 1000; // Set to whatever distance you need
var polygon = (Polygon) referenceLocation.Buffer(distance); // You can also pass in some BufferParameters here

var dataPoints = Session.QueryOver<your_data_point_entity_type>()
    .WhereSpatialRestrictionOn(x => x.point_geom_column)
    .Intersects(polygon)
    .List();
```

As an aside, I may get around to finally implementing the `IsWithinDistance()` function within `NHibernate.Spatial` when I get some free time :) See [this issue](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.Spatial/issues/61) on GitHub.

Comment: Firstly glad to see the author of the library responding here! Thanks for taking the time.
I have seen the answer and hope it is the one that works. I had to move to another project and I cannot ascertain the correctness right now. I will get back to this once I get some time. In the mean time, if someone else finds this working, please do up vote or let me know... Thanks much.

Comment: @BCharlesH No problem - hopefully it'll help others when they search :) I should also note that I'm not the package author, merely an occasional contributor ;)